# Django ORM: All users which have at least one group

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to find all users which are at least in one group.

I found a solution

```
from django import setup

setup()

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user_without_group = User.objects.update_or_create(username='user-without-group')[0]
user_without_group.groups.clear()
query = User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=False).values_list('username', flat=True)
print (query.query)
print list(query)
assert user_without_group.username not in query
```

... but the solution is not nice. Is there a more obvious solution than `groups__isnull=False`?

**update**

Why I think this solution is not nice: I think this is not obvious. It is not easy to read and understand. If you show this to someone who knows Python, but has never used the django ORM, I don't think he will immediately understand what this means.

```
User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Why do you think the solution is not nice?

Comment: @ivissani I updated the question and explained why I think this is not nice.

Comment: If it's a matter of readability I think you have two options, the first one is to explain your query using comments (which, by the way, I find to be a good practice as understanding the intent of queries is not always very easy). The second one would be to write a custom Lookup with a more meaningful name, let's say 'exists' so your query becomes `User.objects.filter(groups__exists=False)`. This lookup should do the same as te `IsNull` lookup.

Comment: @ivissani I read the books "clean code" and "clean coder" and since then I avoid comments. Comments lie. Just five minutes ago I came across an old comments which was just plain wrong. The code changed, the variable and method names were easy to understand. The comment was dated. I removed it, since it was wrong and not needed (in this case).

Comment: Another practice that I find useful in Django is to override the queryset for your model to add common filters as methods. So you can add a method to your `User` queryset called  `with_groups()` or whatever you find appropriate, that, internally, performs the filtering. Then you achieve two things 1) you modularize your code allowing for future changes to be easily implemented and 2) you can be more descriptive of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider adding a readable custom lookup field like `group__at_least_one=True` by [Custom Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-lookups/)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you have against `groups__isnull=False`; it's absolutely fine. Note though that it's exactly equivalent to `groups=None`, which you might find a bit nicer.

Comment: I tested it. I guess you mean `groups=None` is the opposite of `groups__isnull=False`.

Comment: `User.objects.exclude(groups=None)` is how it would be used to get what you're after

Comment: @guettli I would use this and put a comment like: `#Be sure users have at least one group`, comments are python code too, and you can/should use them to add clarity to your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
Group.objects.values_list('user').distinct('user')
```

And you will get unique users only with 1 and more `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

`User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=False).values_list('username')` produces simple SQL:

```
SELECT "users_user"."username" FROM "users_user" 
INNER JOIN "users_user_groups" ON ("users_user"."id" = "users_user_groups"."user_id") 
WHERE "users_user_groups"."group_id" IS NOT NULL
```

Filtering null on a fk shown exactly the same in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull).

Answer (score 1):

A less SQL implementation specific solution would be to use either an `Exists` subquery or a `Count`

```
User.objects.annotate(
    has_groups=Exists(
        User.groups.through.objects.filter(
            user=OuterRef('pk'),
        )
    )
).filter(has_groups=True)

User.objects.annotate(
    groups_count=Count('groups'),
).filter(groups__gte=1)
```

I doubt these solution would perform any faster than `groups__isnull=True`'s inner join though. It'd be great if m2m fields exposed an `__exists` lookup so you could do `filter(groups__exists=True)` and avoid most of this boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, `filter(groups__exists=True)` would be very nice.